# Why are the binaries generated by using Meson / Ninja much larger than those compiled by plain valac?

Tags: binary, ninja, meson-build

Same source file.

directe compile use valac.

```
⭕ valac --pkg gtk+-3.0 -X -lm --pkg libcanberra src/Application.vala 
⭕ ls Application 
-rwxrwxr-x 1 eexpss 48K 05-13 19:59 Application
```

here is part of my meson.build.

```
project('com.github.eexpress.cairo-timer', 'vala', 'c')

# i18n = import('i18n')

executable(
    meson.project_name(),
    'src/Application.vala',
    dependencies: [
        dependency('gtk+-3.0'),
#       dependency('cairo'),
        dependency('libcanberra')
    ],
#   link_args : '-X',
#   link_args : '-lm',
    link_args : ['-X', '-lm',],
    install: true
)
```

and use ninja to compile it.

```
⭕ cd build; ninja
⭕ ls com.github.eexpress.cairo-timer
-rwxrwxr-x 1 eexpss 98K 05-13 17:02 com.github.eexpress.cairo-timer
```

So the binary file is more larger than above one. why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you didn't enable debugging for `valac`, but meson enables it by default.  Add `-g` to `valac` and the output size should be close to equal.

To see how `ninja` and `valac` run the tools to build, enable verbose option by given `-v` to both commands.

The minor size differences are, as I assume, from file names in them.  Compare the outputs, for example, from `readelf --debug-dump=line hello` to see the diff.